# How to navigate to Router outlet using Angular RouterLink?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router, angular12, angular-routerlink

I have a below route defined in my angular 12 app, I am able to navigate to it directly using the browser URL bar. Now I am trying to navigate using hyperlink, like below

```html
<a routerLink="home/1057/view/(sidebar:view)">sidebar</a> <!-- Doesn't work -->
```

or

```html
<a routerLink="/home/1057/view/(sidebar:view)">sidebar</a> <!-- Doesn't work -->
```

> http://localhost/home/1057/view(sidebar:view) - works fine when you directly hit the url, but above `routerLink` is not working, any ideas ?

```js
{
   path: 'view',
   outlet: 'sidebar', // right
   loadChildren: () => import('src/app/entities/sidebar/sidebar.module').then(m => m.SideBarModule)
}
```

Comment: You have `sidebard` instead of `sidebar` as the name of the router outlet. Is that intentional?

Comment: @DM - its corrected now, still the issue is same

Comment: well, try using routLink with binding ... ( see more https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/aux-routes ) ...

Comment: @Vovan_Super - Suppose I have A, B, C components, and I am calling `A/B/C` like above, from component A and router outlet is defined in B for C. Looks like what I am trying is not possible right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

<a [routerLink]="['url path']">

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
[routerLink]="['home/1057/view/sidebar:view']"
```

Comment: its not working, so I tried with brackets, like this  `[routerLink]="['home/1057/view/(sidebar:view)']"` but its not working since its not considering the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Below Snipped solved the problem.

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" 
  [routerLink]="['home/1057/view', 
{ outlets: { 'sidebar': ['view'] } }]" >{{ name }}</a>
```